# Different result when decrypting file in Go and OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, go

I have written the following code to decrypt a file:

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.encrypted")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

mode.CryptBlocks(data, data)

err = ioutil.WriteFile("file.decrypted", data, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I have also decrypted the file using OpenSSL:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in file.encrypted -out file.decrypted -iv $IV -K $KEY
```

Output file from Go program is 8 bytes larger than output file from from OpenSSL.

Tail of hexdump from file generated by OpenSSL:

```
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff                           |........|
```

Tail of hexdump from file generated by Go program:

```
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08  |................|
```

Why is `08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08` appended to file output from Go program?

**EDIT:**

As BJ Black explains, the reason for extra bytes in output from my Go program is PKCS padding.

The file is encrypted with AES in CBC mode and therefore the plain text input shall be a multiple of block size, padding is added to fulfill this requirement. AES has a block size of 16 bytes so the total number of padding bytes will always be between 1 and 16 bytes. Each padding byte has a value equal to the total number of padding bytes which in my case is `0x08`.

So, to find out the amount of padding added to the file, one just have to read the last byte of decrypted file and convert that number to int:

```
paddingBytes := int(data[len(data)-1])
```

The WriteFile function can then be modified like this:

```
err = ioutil.WriteFile("file.decrypted", data[:len(data)-paddingBytes], 0644)
```

Now output from my Go program is identical to the output from OpenSSL.

Comment: Hi John Smith, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for contributing. If you have an answer to your own question, or wish to expand on an answer to a question, please do so in the answer section below. This allows other users to more easily navigate between questions and answers instead of having to parse the text to figure out which one they are looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is PKCS padding, which OSSL is removing for you and Go isn't by default.  See the relevant Reddit post [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/4pkj67/is_pkcs7_the_default_padding_for_newcbcdecrypter/).

Basically, follow the example and you're good to go.